# Delphi PPL TTask Procedure with Parameters

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I do not know how to Create a TTask where I have a Procedure with parameters, without parameters it works but with parameters it does not .

Example

```
procedure TMain.SYNC(AProgressBar: TProgressBar; ASleep: Integer);
var i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 100 do
    begin
      sleep(ASleep);

      TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure
      begin
        AProgressBar.Position:=i;
      end);

    end;
end;
```

Then I would like to create 4 Tasks like this :

```
setlength(Tasks,4);

  Tasks[0] := TTask.Create(SYNC(progressThread1,100));
  Tasks[1] := TTask.Create(SYNC(progressThread2,150));
  Tasks[2] := TTask.Create(SYNC(progressThread3,300));
  Tasks[3] := TTask.Create(SYNC(progressThread4,200));

  Tasks[0].Start;
  Tasks[1].Start;
  Tasks[2].Start;
  Tasks[3].Start;
```

Comment: Use anon method variable capture

Comment: thank you , I googled, but unfortunately I drifted in the wrong direction with this tip, but still it is valid I guess,... just I am not as experienced as you are ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TTask` operates with [anonymous procedures](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi). You can [capture the values](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Anonymous_Methods_Variable_Binding) that you want to pass to your method, eg:

```
SetLength(Tasks, 4);

Tasks[0] := TTask.Create(
  procedure
  begin
    SYNC(progressThread1, 100);
  end
);
Tasks[1] := TTask.Create(
  procedure
  begin
    SYNC(progressThread2, 150);
  end
);
Tasks[2] := TTask.Create(
  procedure
  begin
    SYNC(progressThread3, 300);
  end
);
Tasks[3] := TTask.Create(
  procedure
  begin
    SYNC(progressThread4, 200);
  end
);

Tasks[0].Start;
Tasks[1].Start;
Tasks[2].Start;
Tasks[3].Start;
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending the Remy's answer, you can also write a function which returns an anonymous function that you pass to the task.

```
function MakeSync(AProgressBar: TProgressBar; ASleep: integer): TProc;
begin
  Result :=
    procedure
    begin
      SYNC(AProgressBar, ASleep);
    end;
end;

SetLength(Tasks, 4);

Tasks[0] := TTask.Create(MakeSYNC(progressThread1, 100));
Tasks[1] := TTask.Create(MakeSYNC(progressThread2, 150));
Tasks[2] := TTask.Create(MakeSYNC(progressThread3, 300));
Tasks[3] := TTask.Create(MakeSYNC(progressThread4, 200));

Tasks[0].Start;
Tasks[1].Start;
Tasks[2].Start;
Tasks[3].Start;
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending Remy's answer.

The loop 0..100 calling `TThread.Queue` with index `i` suffers from updating the progressbar with the `i` reference value, rather than the passed value.

To better view the consequence of this, remove the sleep call and add the i value to a memo. This will reveal a sequence similar to this:

```
42
101
101
101
...
101
```

Here is an example of how to capture the value of `i` when calling `TThread.Queue`:

```
procedure TMain.SYNC(AProgressBar: TProgressBar; ASleep: Integer);
  function CaptureValue( ix : Integer) : TThreadProcedure;
  begin
    Result :=
      procedure
      begin
        AProgressBar.Position := ix;
      end;
  end;
var i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 100 do
    begin
      sleep(ASleep);
      TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread, CaptureValue(i) );
    end;
end;
```